# Spring OAuth2 determine if principal is oauth2_client or basic user

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an *ResourceServer* app (`@EnableResourceServer`) connected to an *AuthorizationServer* (`@EnableAuthorizationServer`).

I want to support two grant types:

1. Authorization code
2. Client credentials

Both are working correctly, but how can I differentiate if `Principal` is *basic user* (using authorization code flow) or *client* (using client credentials)?

If is not directly possible do you think I should create a specific role/authority or scope (which is better?) to determine when `Principal` is a client?

Comment: Once the User is authenticated, via any medium, it's same after that. I think roles would be the ideal way to distinguish between different types of Users.

Comment: @WeareBorg Ok that confirm what I thought. My use case was to has basic user (member) and app user (non human). But app user will be a client a not a user (in data model)

Comment: What do you mean by APP-user? Android app? If that's the case, then you can also authenticate the app-user normally by adding JSESSIONID cookie for every secure request.

Comment: Not related to mobile, app-user is user used by external/background tasks generally to administrate something or retrieve some information. Use case offer a kind of SDK for Ops.

Comment: Okay... Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've authenticated, you should have an instance of org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication set in the SecurityContext which contains details of both the authenticated user and the client they are using.

This has an isClientOnly() method which will return true if the client credentials grant is used.
You can also check this in the @PreAuthorize tags if you've enables the OAuth2 expressions:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.isClient")
```

Comment: deprecated solution, now OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods is deprecated. I cannot find replacement